# apply where condition while connecting repeater to database

Tags: asp.net

I have two pages one of which named is category and other is product and I have used repeater in these two pages. I want that when I click on any category on category page then it must be jump to product page and select specific products that are related to this category, but I am confuse that when I select any category it jumps to the product page but displays all products not only related to this category but also all other products that relates to other categories.

Comment: can you share your code

Answer (score 0):

when you redirected to product page pass category id in query string and then on product page fetch only those product from database whose category id same as you have received from query string.